# Matplotlib python set marker at event

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxwidgets

So I have a function that doesn't use the `plot` call directly since the application is meant to run for a long time. So instead I append data to the plot using `myPlot` but when I try to append data points to the twinx() subplot using a different style (blue diamonds for example,  the values don't show up. ax2lines are the twinx() subplot lines ..

How do I append a marker on the line (either `self.lines` or `self.ax2lines` really)  in case of xFail happening?

```
    self.ax2 = self.ax.twinx()
    self.ax2lines, = self.ax2.plot([],[])
    self.ax2lines.set_marker('D')
    self.ax2lines.set_color('cornflowerblue')
    self.ax2lines.set_markersize(10.0)
    self.lines, = self.ax.plot([],[])


def myPlot(self, data1, xFails, yFails):
    #self.ax.clear()
    xData = range(len(data1))

    self.lines.set_ydata( data1)
    self.lines.set_xdata( xData)
    if xFails[xData[-1]]:
        print "something happened - mark it on the graph"
        self.ax2lines.set_ydata(yFails)
        self.ax2lines.set_xdata(xFails)   ## Doesn't do anything
```

Comment: That marker size is REALLY small. Try upping it to 100 and see if you see anything.

Comment: @mauve tried that, still did not plot. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the plot to be updated automatically you have to be in *interactive mode* (i.e. call `plt.ion()` at some point) and the explicitly tell the plot to update by calling `plt.draw()` after you set the new data.

Comment: Just to make sure, if i have `import matplotlib` and not `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` on what object would i call `ion()` ? The figure or the canvas or the axes ?

Comment: Does the figure window show up while your code runs? Do you call `show()` somewhere? `ion()` seems to exist only as a `pyplot` function but if your figure is shown before the program stops you're fine. [`draw`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pyplot.draw#matplotlib.pyplot.draw) can maybe also called on the figure directly.

Comment: yes, the code works apart from the second axis' plot points not showing up.. Everytime myPlot is called, the axis updates the regular values (line segments). I want to be able to use markers in that line without calling plot. Regards

Comment: So the line segments are updated but not the markers? For the same line? Is the print statement ever executed?

Comment: yes, the `if` fires and everything is done, however, apparently only setting y and xdata does not plot lines. If i do  `self.ax2lines.set_markersize(100.0)` and in myPlot do a self.ax2.plot(xData, yData, 'oD') both the huge (100.0 size ) and the original size markers will show up .. So that means I have to fire a standard call to `plot` to get markers to work?


Or,  there's probably no support for adding dots on a line like there is support for adding values to a list (of lines) ?

Comment: Can you print out yFails and xFails? Do they contain valid stuff for plotting? Inside the range of your axis limits?

Comment: Xfails and yfails will be lists, each holding x and y coordinates. They are printed fine each time and have correct data. The thing that bugs me is that apparently you *have* to use the plot call to make markers show.. Unless there's a way of plotting markers at specific x/y coords in the first subplot (i.e `self.ax`)?